# can you pre-compose ggplot elements for repeated use?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm creating several plots that share common graphical elements (for example, say I want the x-axis on all plots to be categories in a certain order, with the same axis label, and the tick labels always rotated).  In `ggplot2` that would mean adding the following terms to my plot object:

```
xlab("My axis title") + 
scale_x_discrete(limits=my_predefined_category_order) +
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
```

Since I'm adding those elements to several plots, I thought I'd refactor my code so I could change them all in one place.  It works if I assign each element to its own function, like this:

```
my_xlab <- function() xlab("My axis title")
my_xlim <- function() scale_x_discrete(limits=my_predefined_category_order)
my_xrot <- function() theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90, vjust=0.5))
```

followed by

```
mydata %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=whatever, y=something)) +
    geom_point() + 
    my_xlab() + my_xlim() + my_xrot()
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is combine `my_xlab`, `my_xlim`, and `my_xrot` into a single composite element (call it `my_xaxis`) that would set all three graphical elements at the same time.  I tried this:

```
my_xaxis <- function() my_xlab() %+% my_xlim() %+% my_xrot()
```

followed by

```
mydata %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x=whatever, y=something)) +
    geom_point() + 
    my_xaxis()
```

but it doesn't work.  Then I realized that `%+%` returns `NULL`:

```
class(ylim(0, 1))
# [1] "ScaleContinuousPosition" "ScaleContinuous" "Scale" "ggproto"
class(ylab("my ylabel"))
# [1] "labels"
class(ylim(0, 1) %+% ylab("my ylabel"))
# [1] "NULL"
```

which explains why what I tried doesn't work.  Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Comment: You can put everything into a list as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23177961/2461552).  It looks like `theme` can also be used in the list.

Comment: awesome, thanks.  Not sure how I missed that other question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23177961/2461552), you can put all these into a list and then add it via `+` to your plot.  This list can include `theme` elements.

```
my_xaxis = list(xlab("My axis title"),
             scale_x_discrete( limits = my_predefined_category_order ),
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) )
```

Here's what it could look like in practice.

```
my_predefined_category_order = c("8", "6", "4")
my_xaxis = list(xlab("My axis title"),
             scale_x_discrete( limits = my_predefined_category_order ),
             theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5)) )

p = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
    geom_point()
p + my_xaxis
```

[image]