# Consolidate block of ggplot specifications into single function for application to multiple datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many subsets of data that I would like to apply functions to and then plot. I have tailored my ggplot code to be what I'd like, aesthetically, and don't want to fill my notebook with these same long lists of specifications for every independent plot. Is it possible to take something like the following blocks of ggplot text, where

```
p = [some generic ggplot]

p = p + guides(colour = guide_legend(title = "year_collected", ncol = 2, keywidth = 1, keyheight = 1))

p = p + theme_minimal() + 
        theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
              axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(0,20,0,0)),
              text=element_text(size=8, color="black",family="Arial"),
              panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
              #axis.ticks = element_blank(),
              legend.key.size = unit(.1, "in"),
              legend.spacing.x = unit(.01,"in"),
              legend.position = "bottom",
              plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

p$layers <- p$layers[-1]
```

and use the R function options to capture all of these specifications and additions?

Thanks!

Comment: "Can ggplot theme formatting be saved as an object? - Stack Overflow" https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23173915/can-ggplot-theme-formatting-be-saved-as-an-object

Comment: Instead of adding it to every plot, have you looked into the `theme_set()` function?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can feed any lines of ggplot code into a list (with items comma separated) and add that:

```
my_theme_lines <- list(theme_minimal(),
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_text(margin=margin(0,20,0,0)),
        text=element_text(size=8, color="black",family="Arial"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        #axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        legend.key.size = unit(.1, "in"),
        legend.spacing.x = unit(.01,"in"),
        legend.position = "bottom",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)))



ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  my_theme_lines
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to define a custom `ggplot` theme, just use this template:

```
theme_custom <- function(){ 
  #font <- "Georgia"   # assign font family up front
  theme_minimal() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    # custom elements go here
    theme(
    )
}
```

Now with the question's settings.

```
theme_user3353556 <- function(){ 
  font <- "Arial"     # assign font family up front
  theme_minimal() %+replace%    #replace elements we want to change
    # custom elements go here
    theme(
      panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
      text = element_text(size = 8, color = "black"),
      axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(0, 20, 0, 0)),
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
      #axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      legend.key.size = unit(0.1, "in"),
      legend.spacing.x = unit(0.01,"in"),
      legend.position = "bottom",
      plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)
    )
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_user3353556()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for, I appreciate the help!